# Set query params if exists?

Tags: angular

I have this link:

```
<a [routerLink]="[menu.url ||'/']" [queryParams]="{procesId: menu.refParameter3}">
```

What i want is to check if this `menu.refParamter3` exists if exists then add it in `queryParams`, if not leave empty. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is put an *ngIf inside the  tag that checks if menu.refParameter3 exists then display the necessary template

Something like this

```
   <!-- if refParameter3 exists -->   
    <a  *ngIf="menu.refParameter3" [routerLink]="[menu.url ||'/']" [queryParams]="{procesId: menu.refParameter3}">
   <!-- if there is no refParameter3 -->
     <a  *ngIf="!menu.refParameter3" [routerLink]="[menu.url ||'/']">
```

Comment: i cannot use div because then css is mixed up, and everying brokes

Comment: @None You dont need to use div. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should set your variable in the controller.

For example:

```
$scope.procesId;
if ($scope.menu.refParameter3) {
    $scope.procesId = $scope.menu.refParameter3;
}
```

And when you pass this variable it will be either empty or containing the refParameter3 value.

Comment: im using angular 2

Comment: This version is angularjs ( 1.x )